# Why not namespace custom class/instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, methods, overriding

In Objectice-C or Ruby, why don't we prefix (with our class prefix) our custom classes' class/instance methods to prevent conflicts, e.g., if Objective-C or Ruby later adds a method with the same name to the super class?

Reasoning:

An Objective-C good practice is to prefix (with your class prefix) methods of categories you create to add methods to classes you don't own.

For example:

```
@interface NSString (XYZAdditions)

+ (NSString)xyz_emptyString
{
    return @"";
}

- (NSArray)xyz_words
{
    // Split the string into words.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather my code have predictable, non-warted method names than be theoretically bullet proof against some unknown future change that will likely never happen.  It feels somewhat like a [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) situation.

Rails *dumps all over* the standard libraries, and if they can seem to pull it off without much headache, anything I do will pale in comparison, I may as well shoot for my ideal method names and fix problems as they occur and no sooner.

I've only done a little Objective-C, but the only "namespacing" I've seen has been adding your XYZClass prefix to the beginning of class names since that's a real problem as class names are way more likely to collide.